# Azure Cosmos db throwing Socket Exceptions

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am using `azure cosmos` db with .net core 2.1 application. I am using `gremlin driver` with this. It's working fine but after every few days it start throwing socket exception on server and we have to recycle IIS pool. Average per day hits are **10000**. 
Now we are using default gateway mode. Should we have to switch to direct mode as it might be a firewall [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips)  ?
Here is the implementation:

```
  private  DocumentClient GetDocumentClient( CosmosDbConnectionOptions configuration)
    {
                    _documentClient = new DocumentClient(
                          new Uri(configuration.Endpoint),
                          configuration.AuthKey,
                          new ConnectionPolicy());
                    //create database if not exists
                    _documentClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = configuration.Database });
                    return _documentClient;
    }
```

and in startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton(x => GetDocumentClient(cosmosDBConfig));
```

and here is how we are communicating with cosmos db:

```
        private DocumentClient _documentClient;
        private DocumentCollection _documentCollection;
        private CosmosDbConnectionOptions _cosmosDBConfig;

        public DocumentCollectionFactory(DocumentClient documentClient, CosmosDbConnectionOptions cosmosDBConfig)
        {
            _documentClient = documentClient;
            _cosmosDBConfig = cosmosDBConfig;

        }


        public async Task<DocumentCollection> GetProfileCollectionAsync()
        {
            if (_documentCollection == null)
            {
                _documentCollection = await _documentClient.CreateDocumentCollectionIfNotExistsAsync(
              UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_cosmosDBConfig.Database),
              new DocumentCollection { Id = _cosmosDBConfig.Collection },
              new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = _cosmosDBConfig.Throughput });
                return _documentCollection;
            }
            return _documentCollection;

        }
```

and then:

```
        public async Task CreateProfile(Profile profile)
        {
            var graphCollection = await _graphCollection.GetProfileCollectionAsync();
            var createQuery = GetCreateQuery(profile);
            IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = _documentClient.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(graphCollection, createQuery);
            if(query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is this all the code in your application or are you by any chance also creating httpclients somewhere else?

Comment: No I am using Gremlin

Comment: updated the question with more details

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that for communication with CosmosDB you are using `HttpClient`. The application should share a single instance of `HttpClient`.
Every time you make a connection after `HttpClient` disposal there are still a bunch of connections in the state of `TIME_WAIT`. This means that the connection was closed on one side ( OS ) but it is in "*waiting for additional packets*" state.

By default, Windows may hold this connection in this state for 240 seconds. There is a limit to how quickly OS can open new sockets. All this may lead to `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` exception.

[Very good article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) that explains in details why and how this problem appears digging into TCP diagram and explaining with more details.

**UPDATED**
Possible solution.
You are using the default `ConnectionPolicy` object. That object has a property called `IdleTcpConnectionTimeout` which controls the amount of idle time after which unused connections are closed. By default, idle connections are kept open indefinitely. The value must be greater than or equal to 10 minutes.

So the code could look like:

```
private  DocumentClient GetDocumentClient( CosmosDbConnectionOptions configuration)
{
    _documentClient = new DocumentClient(
        new Uri(configuration.Endpoint),
        configuration.AuthKey,
        new ConnectionPolicy() { 
            IdleTcpConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,10,0) 
        });
    //create database if not exists
    _documentClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(new Database { Id = configuration.Database });
    return _documentClient;
}
```

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy?view=azure-dotnet) to ConnectionPolicy Class documentation

Comment: No, I am not using HttpClient. I am using Gremlin instead

Comment: I took a look at Gremlin source. Under the hood, it uses 'ClientWebSocket'. So the problem may be the same. If it's possible in prod machine to take a look at `netstat` it would show you the situation with the current sockets. If you'll see a lot of sockets in TIME_WAIT state I would suggest to use Gremlin only as a query builder and send it with Cosmos SDK.

Comment: can switching to direct mode may help?

Comment: I think I found a problem. You are using default `ConnectionPolicy`. The is a property called `IdleTcpConnectionTimeout` which controls the amount of idle time after which unused connections are closed. By default, idle connections are kept open indefinitely. Value must be greater than or equal to 10 minutes. 
Try to set it to 10 minutes or some.

Comment: can you share any link by which I can do that?

Comment: actually it's strange but I don't have IdleTcpConnectionTimeout property available in ConnectionPolicy class

Comment: @Ask are your ConnectionPolicy comes from Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client namespace?

Comment: yes, it comes from Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client

Comment: @Ask then It should be there. Please check version

Comment: @Ask what was the problem? Did my answer help you somehow? If so, could you accept my answer?

Comment: are you using the latest version of gremlin client, this was fixed in 3.4.1 i believe